# Create a specified chunk of a library that is not within all entry points

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a project with three entry points and a shared library, that looks like this:

```
LibA -- EntryA
    \-- EntryB
        EntryC
```

What I would like to do is to put `LibA` in a common chunk, even though it is not in EntryC. I tried with the CommonsChunk plugin, but what happens is that my defined chunk gets `LibA`, but also `EntryA` and `EntryB` get the library.

According to the [documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code) creating a chunk should remove the libraries from the entries, but I can't seem to get it work - when I remove `EntryC` it works, so I suspect webpack to not force it into the common chunk because it knows that `EntryC` does not use it.

Can I override that somehow?